# making a php function that If mysql returns 0 rows, return false

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get the function below to return TRUE if it finds a matching row, and FALSE if it finds 0 rows.

```
function IsOpenEvent($id) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events`
                             WHERE `access` = 'public'
                               AND `id` = '$id'
                             LIMIT 1")
                or die(mysql_error());
    if ($result) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`return mysql_num_rows($result) != 0;`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Comment: I like the kind of questions where I can answer with one line of code :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    return false
else 
    return true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return (bool) mysql_num_rows($result)
```

Answer (score 0):

just to let you know, you should really be calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$id`, otherwise you're leaving an SQL injection vulnerability in your code.